# Different response on NodeJS and Postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, http, postman

I want to write a script with `nodejs` that gets a set of rules from `http://hl7.org/fhir`. For example, when I do this request on `Postman` (http://hl7.org/fhir/address-use) I get a valid `JSON` response:

[image]

However, when I use the `nodejs` code below which is generated by `Postman`, I get an `html` as response.

```
var http = require("http");

var options = {
  "method": "GET",
  "hostname": "hl7.org",
  "port": "80",
  "path": "/fhir/address-use",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "accept": "application/json"
  }
};

var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
  var chunks = [];

  res.on("data", function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });

  res.on("end", function () {
    var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    console.log(body.toString());
  });
});

req.end();
```

If you try to go to the url in your browser, it says that the url was moved to another page, but `Postman` gets the correct results anyway. I also tried to get the url that it moved, but it returns `html` response also.

How can I make my script work just as `Postman`?

**EDIT:**

I tried `request` package as recommended in another question. Here is the code:

```
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'GET',
  url: 'http://hl7.org:80/fhir/address-use',
  headers: 
   { 
     accept: 'application/json',
     'content-type': 'application/json' } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

But the result didn't change. It gets the same `html` response.

Comment: Why are you setting `Content-Type` on a GET request? There is no request body to describe the type of. `cache-control` is a response header, it has no place on a request.

Comment: Because I am tired of getting `html`, I can put any header that contains `json` now :) I know it is not required but I don't think it cause a problem.

Comment: Then you probably implemented the answers incorrectly.

Comment: The answer is "Use `request`". `Postman` generates code also for `request` package. So, I don't think I implemented it incorrectly.

Comment: You can also use axios: `axios.get('http://hl7.org/fhir/address-use/', {headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}})`, which follow redirect automatically (5 times max by default)

Comment: By default, Postman will follow the Location header in all 301/302 responses automatically. To make a test, you can set the **Automatically follow redirects** setting to No.

Comment: @BünyaminSarıgül — There are several answers. One of them says "use request", but you are using http.request, not request.

Comment: @Quentin I assume you didn't see the edited part of the question. I used request.

Comment: @shaochuancs `axios` not logging any response (not even error), I couldn't make it work

Comment: @BünyaminSarıgül `axios.get` returns Promise object. In order to get response/error, you need to register callback function with `.then` or `.catch`: `axios.get(...).then(function(res) {console.log(res.data)})`

Comment: @shaochuancs yes, I did that just like in its documentation. But not responded anything. I wonder if it has no connection timeout and keep trying to connect but fails.

Comment: hmmm, I guess maybe it's due to your network environment?

Comment: @shaochuancs still there is no problem on `postman`

Comment: I also had a problem with redirects and node request even though followAllRedirects was set to true in options.  Ran across article that said set these options instead  simple = false resolveWithFullResponse = true  I also set follow all redirects to false